Does Rust allow ownership changed by deref a violation of sole-ownership principle?
I am thinking the idea behind the rules of ownership in Rust,
and what makes me confused is that:
Given

reference is borrowing instead of owning;
there is only one owner of
data;

The following code which use a mutable reference to change the data owner is still workable. Doesn't this violate the previous rules ?
fn main() {
  let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
  //let ref_v = &v;
  let ref_i = &mut v[0];
  *ref_i = 10;
  println!("{v:?}");

  let mut v2 = vec![1, 2, 3];
  //let ref_v = &v;
  let ref_v2 = &mut v2;
  *ref_v2 = vec![10, 20, 30];
  println!("{v2:?}");
}


Borrowing doesn't mean you cannot mutate. As a metaphor, consider borrowing a pen. You use it, therefore changing its amount of ink (mutating its properties), but you are allowed to do so. In general, the only thing about borrows in Rust is that they are temporary; they need to return to their owner eventually.

The ownership analogy to Rust's "ownership" model is not perfect.
let mut v2: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];

Here,  we say "v2 owns a Vec<i32>". But we can't say "v2 owns this specific instance of Vec<i32>". Rust doesn't even really have a concept of an "instance", unlike many other languages.
This means that a mutable reference to v2 is allowed to do anything as long as it leaves a valid value of type Vec<i32> in v2. This includes replacing the value with another one, or even moving out of it and moving a different value back in (see mem::replace).
If we continue ChayimFriedman's pen analogy, a mutable borrow of a pen is allowed to steal the borrowed pen if it gives a different pen (of the same type) to the owner.

To consider a an alternative analogy say you borrow a €10 note from a friend. They aren't going to insist they get the same note back. But they aren't going to be happy if you give them a $10 note instead.

you are not transferring the ownership. if the ownership was transferred, this line would not work:
println!("{v2:?}");

If ownership of v2 was transferred, then trying to use v2 after the transfer would result in a compile-time error because v2 would no longer be valid in the current scope.
